# @font-face font-size rendered larger in some browsers than others

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, font-face, chromium, font-size

i have created a header on my website that uses custom font-faces and have applied a size with pixels (61). and for some unknown (to me) reason the font is rendered nearly twice as large in ie9 and tor than in chromium and firefox. there are no other css settings that appear to me to be relevant (e.g. no font-weight:bold or similar settings). other font-faces appear to render close to or exactly the same size between browsers.

i've exhausted my ideas on what is the cause of this.. if anyone knows, i'd appreciate some assistance. you can view the header here: http://www.infiniteeureka.com 
- the cream words 'infinite eureka' are the ones in focus; the multi coloured smaller words render as desired in both browsers.

Comment: I'm afraid there's not much you can do. read this http://blog.typekit.com/2011/01/26/css-properties-that-affect-type-rendering/

Comment: thanks for the link, though i did not see any direct info there that explains what is occurring in my example.. the font size difference is big.. not a few pixels...  200%. 
oh.. i just tested the issue again and now firefox renders the correct size.. 
internet explorer 9 and tor do not.

Answer (score 0):

Firefox has known issues rendering web fonts. I don't really have time to research your problem, but they have Mozilla-specific CSS to deal with these bugs, font-feature-settings in Firefox. I'd start by reading here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/font-feature-settings?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=CSS%2F-moz-font-feature-settings

Comment: thanks; i have now found that, for whatever reason, firefox is rendering ok and ie9 and tor are rendering too big. possibly firefox increased a version in between me first noticing and now.