# Google Bar Chart Annotation Prints Larger Font Than Browser Displays with Firefox

Tags: firefox, svg, charts, google-visualization, printing-web-page

**Problem:**
Google Bar Chart displays annotations correctly in the browser (Firefox 43.0.3) but during printing will enlarge the font of certain annotations making them unreadable.

- *This problem does **not** occur using Chrome (ver 47.0.2526.106 - 64bit) or Safari (ver 9.0.2).*
- Interestingly IE 11 (11.0.26) seems
  to print the annotation fonts fine but doesn't handle other aspects
  of Google Chart printing.
- All testing done on Mac OSX (10.11.2) and
  Windows 7 Enterprise.

**Question:**
Is there a way to fix this problem in Firefox: printing annotations in correct font size?  The only solution I have is to **not** use annotations or create a separate 'print' page that is identical to the view except all annotations are turned off.  Not ideal solutions.  Curious that I could not find this specific 'annotation printing problem' discussed anywhere else.  Appreciate guidance, thoughts, brain-storming, work-arounds.

**Research:**
I assume this is a browser-specific rendering problem when printing SVG (format in which Google renders the charts). The only solution seems to be using the `chart.getImageURI()` method which returns a base-64 encoded PNG string [(ref link)](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing). Doing this however will make your charts no longer interactive (because they will render as PNG) and it doesn't work on IE<9.0 (if that's an issue for you).  Perhaps another issue might be the typeface used by Google Chart annotations not being recognized when printing?

**Possible related articles:**

- [@font-face font-size rendered larger in some browsers than others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14365948/font-face-font-size-rendered-larger-in-some-browsers-than-others)

**Example:**
The problem exists even on the Google API documentation page:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/barchart

[image: Example of Firefox Print Rendering Problem of Google Bar Chart Annotation]

Comment: have tried setting a specific font and size?

Comment: Yes.  To accomplish this is a bit weird but ultimately it didn't work.  I couldn't seem to set font size in array itself (for each bar) but could do so in options.  This is apparently a known issue.  Color can be set as a style in the array but not font.  This creates two areas for annotation which is kind of strange.  I will go back and retest though using different approach and report back with example.

Comment: When fontSize in annotations was changed to <2, the problem seemed to resolve but of course you could no longer read the annotations. `'annotations': {
       textStyle: {
       fontSize: 2
     }`.  This seems to be an issue with how Firefox is rendering the SVG graph.  I have submitted a bug ticket at bugzilla.mozilla.org

Comment: one option might be to use [`getImageURI`](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/printing) to generate an image of the chart for printing...

Comment: Thanks @WhiteHat. Seems that and removing annotations prior to printing might be an option (noted in Research above).  Neither ideal but both would work.